# Falling objects in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, game-physics

I have 20 different sprites. I essentially want a "flow" of them to be constantly falling from the top and disappearing when they reach the bottom. Essentially, imagine rain where each drop is a random sprite. I want each sprite to fall with a random rotation and each "drop" to be a random sprite from my selection of 20.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I've never made a game before and this is my first time working with SpriteKit. I'm using Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of arc4random to get a random sprite from your selection of 20 sprites by adding those sprites to a group. arc4random will also be able to get a random rotation for you.

For them to fall down from the top to the bottom, you can apply -gravity to them or apply a -impulse.

To check whether they have reached the bottom, get the y value when they disappear off the bottom of the screen and use that as a comparision value and then use removeFromParent().

Alternatively the third method could be to use the movement of SKAction and simply adjust their Y coordinate. At the end of the completion block just use removeFromParent().